# Error 404 with structure after the 2nd segment

Tags: segments, error-pages

I am using structure, and therefore, sometimes I have more than the standard 2 segements (template_group/template).

the error page get's triggered whenever the first or the second segment is incorrect, but it's not triggered as soon as there is a third segment.

I've tried this on several structure sites and seems to be consistent.

I also used libraree on these sites.

are you experiencing the same thing?
is there any way to overcome this?

cheers
stefan

Comment: Are you using the Freebie addon?

Comment: yes... but I have tried it with or without it... did you try on one of your installs with structure?

Comment: I didn't, it's just another piece of the puzzle. Have you tried without your htaccess file?

Comment: yup... it's the same...

Comment: what's your url structure? stupid question but does the url structure exist within the Structure site tree?

Comment: sorry - no the url does not exist in structure, that's why it's generating the 404...

Comment: it's when there's 3 segments involved that this happens, with the 2 first being valid or not. 

E.g. /contact/addres[typo]s get's a valid 404 page and 
/contact/address/[anything] does not get a valid 404 page. 

but pages with a correct third segement render fine: 
e.g: /contact/address/thanks

Comment: can you share your template code?

Comment: also a screenshot of your Structure tree would be useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Strict URLs turned off, then an incorrect third segment is most likely parsing the index.html template of the default template group. Unless that template has a way to verify the URL against an entry, it will parse normally everything that it can.

So, I'd work in a 404 solution for your default template. Two different options could be:

```
{if segment_3}{embed="templategroup/404"}{/if}
```

OR

```
{if segment_3}{redirect="/"}{/if}
```

Comment: hi - thanks for your answer... but that won't work, since with structure you CAN have a third segment! EE just can't detect whether it's a correct one or not.

Comment: Did you test? What were the results?

Comment: hm, no - I didn't test it... and when I come to think of it, your solution could work since EE will only recognize a third segment when the {triggers:segement_3} is not present... ha... that might really work. did you test it on your end?

Comment: I don't have the problem. :)

Comment: ok - i'll try it and report back! thanks already!

Comment: And this might be helpful too: http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/images/ExpressionEngine_url_schematic.png